# il y a + à + infinitive

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires, à

Could someone please explain the grammar exemplified by the *il n’y avait pas à s’étonner* structure in the following:

> Il n’y avait pas à s’étonner qu’il lui soit arrivé la même chose avec son employeur à lui.

In particular, what is the role of *à* and of the infinitive?

It seems to me that the structure allows the infinitive to be used adjectivally ("it is not surprising..."). Would that be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un emploi du verbe *avoir* avec la préposition *à* comme [auxiliaire de modalité radicale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_modal) pour *devoir déontique* (Wikipédia), l'idée d'*obligation/nécessité* [have to]. Dans l'exemple la tournure est impersonnelle et négative, donc signifiant l'absence l'obligation ou nécessité [not have to].

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir), III, A.  : 1. **Avoir à + inf.** impliquant une idée, plus ou moins nette, d'obligation. Être contraint de. *J'ai une lettre à écrire* « je dois écrire une lettre » [...] (voir aussi remarques I.B.4 b [ici](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) sur l'impact du changement de position du complément de l'infinitif.)

[Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A3461) : IV. Emplois idiomatiques.

1. *Avoir à* suivi de l’infinitif. Devoir, être plus ou moins impérativement contraint de, obligé de. *J’ai à vous remercier. Tu as une visite à faire. On avait à craindre une erreur. Vous avez à prendre vos précautions. J’ai à parler dans cette réunion. J’ai à écrire une lettre, j’ai une lettre à écrire. Elle avait à prendre un médicament. Nous n’avons rien de particulier à signaler. Je n’ai rien à faire.* [...]

Aussi au [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0) et au LBU14 § 821 b (« *Il y a* connaît une construction analogue [à *avoir à* + infinitif]: IL Y A beaucoup À faire. IL Y AURAIT beaucoup de choses À dire. IL n'Y A qu'À patienter ».).

> [Il n'était pas nécessaire de/on ne devait pas (*It was not necessary
> to/we don't have to i.e. no need to*] ...s’étonner qu’il lui soit
> arrivé la même chose avec son employeur à lui.

---

L'idée générale : *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> § 821 b)

[image]

Des sens particuliers : *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> § 784 b 2)

[image]

Comment: You’ve answered my question. Thank you. And thank you for the reference.

Comment: Tiens tiens… ex post facto ? Non ? Aussi, « On est contraint de parier » ? « Il est nécessaire de parier » ? Déontique, hein ?

Comment: @LPH Je pensais que tu en avais assez. J'ai justement indiqué _des sens particuliers_ pour faire comprendre que c'est différent de l'idée générale « devoir ». S'agit-il d'un de ces emplois qui se trouve en question ? Tout ça est documenté dans notre [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63080703#63080703). Je préfère que les apprenants n'aient pas à se fier à tes approximations et à ton verbiage...

Comment: _Il y a (fort, gros) à parier_ : il est presque certain, avoir de fortes raisons de croire que. / _Il y a à boire et à manger_ : question d'aspects contradictoires. / _Il n'y a pas à dire_ : il faut se rendre à l’évidence. / _Il n'y à pas à sortir de là_ : Se tenir exactement au point qui est essentiel dans une négociation, une discussion. / _Il n'y a qu'à..._ : il suffit de. Où sont ces nuances et ces informations dans ta réponse ? Nulle part. C'est qu'il faut aller voir au dictionnaire pour ces termes et verbes plutôt que de rester obnubilé par le fait qu'on ne trouve pas tout dans _avoir_.

Answer (score 3):

"*[il n'y a pas à](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il%20n%27y%20a%20pas%20%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)*" is an idiomatic expression. It is not found in the TLFI nor in the Wiktionnaire, and not the dictionary of the Académie, strangely enough. The translation in this sentence is as given in the answer by [user Roger Vadim](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52506/17649): "there is no reason".

you could also say in some cases "there is no necessity".

"à" is part of this idiom; after "à" you have to use a verb in the infinitive. It is an idiom to which corresponds an affirmative form. ([il y avait à](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il%20y%20avait%20%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

([Enquête parlementaire sur l'insurrection du 18 mars 1871](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Enqu%C3%AAte_parlementaire_sur_l_insurrectio/amdIBODK53EC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&pg=PA399&printsec=frontcover)) Quand nous entrâmes à la mairie, nous trouvâmes beaucoup de choses à faire : il y avait à donner suite à l'armement de la garde nationale, à son habillement ; il y avait à organiser le service des cantines, de la bienfaisance. (*translation:*  "*it was necessary to*").

([Histoire de France depuis les temps les plus reculés jusqu'à la révolution - 1848](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Histoire_de_France_depuis_les_temps_les/njYVAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover)) Il y avait à craindre que son refus ne fût d'autant plus ferme , qu'il serait appuyé par le prince de Condé ("*there was grounds for*", "*there was good reason to*").

(["Ce n'est qu'un début"](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ce_n_est_qu_un_d%C3%A9but/RehWAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&dq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&printsec=frontcover)) On avait aussi décidé que, si jamais il y avait une provocation policière, s'il y avait à affronter les C.R.S., on avait à y prendre part ("*if it had been necessary to*")

Several possibilities of occurrence of this form are confusing. Here is one among others: the construction is not that of the same idiom.

([Travail social - Volume 3 -](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Travail_social/D6NCAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&dq=%22il+y+avait+%C3%A0%22&printsec=frontcover))   Il s'était demandé quel intérêt il y avait à continuer à vivre (*Here "à" is the normal preposition associated with "intérêt": "il y avait un intérêt à continuer à vivre" or "il n'y avait pas un intérêt à continuer à vivre"; plain "there was"*)

Comment: You’ve answered my question. Thank you. However I have accepted an alternative answer, since it provides more context.

Comment: @justerman I do not agree with this alternative answer since the turn "ily a à" is impersonal; "il" does not represent anyone; it's just as in the so called "présentatif" "il y a". Moreover, there is a difference between necessity and constraint: you are not necessarily constrained to do what is necessary. Finally, in "il n'y avait pas à s'étonner", there is no idea of constraint, but the idea of an absence of reasons.

Comment: Les exemples et le propos au LBU confirment que la tournure est analogue à celle identifiée avec _avoir à + infinitif_ et c'est ça l'essentiel. Dire que ça ne cadre pas parce que la modalité peut être nuancée et que c'est un tour obscur non documenté est à mon avis erroné.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Vous négligez quelque chose d'important. Dans toutes les références que vous utilisez il n'est pas question de « y »; la forme verbale est « avoir à », conjuguée à toutes les personnes. La forme que l'on considère n'est pas celle-là, c'est « **y** avoir à » et elle n'est pas conjuguée normalement; seulement la troisième personne du singulier résulte en une construction correcte, et en plus le pronom est impersonnel : il ne peut pas avoir de référent. C'est donc un tour idiomatique. On est en présence d'un idiomatisme du même type que « **il y avoir** ». (1/2)

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle   TLFi : « 1. Il y a + subst. (ou pron. prédicatif). _Il y a_ est un présentatif pur comme voici* et voilà*, il peut être suivi d'un subst. précédé d'un art. ou d'un adj. indéf., d'un adj. poss., d'un adj. dém., ou encore de l'art. défini. _Il y a_ opère un choix parmi tous les possibles  ». Les tours associés (voir le TLFi) sont « **il y a de quoi** »  et « **il n'y a qu'à** » suivi de l'infinitif, mais le tour «  **il y a à** » ne figure pas parmi ce groupe auquel il appartient. Comme ces tours associés ont leur propre signification, ce tour-ci a aussi la sienne. (2/2)

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle La construction de « il y a » est bien analogue à celle de « avoir », mais le sens n'est plus « posséder ». Non, le sens ne découle pas de « avoir », mais de « il **y** avoir, comme la section du TLFi à ce sujet le montre; ne pas négliger « y », qui n'est pas analysable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143227/discussion-between-lph-and-crissy-froth-seapickle).

Answer (score 2):

I would translate *il n'y avait pas à s'étonner que...* as *there was no reason to be he surprised that...*. Although perhaps not the most semantically exact translation, this represents equivalent grammatical structures.

In general, French often uses infinitive where English uses present participle/adjective. However, in this case translation by a verbs seems even more precise.

Preposition *à* introduces the infinitive, roughly similar to the function of *to* in my translation, but French doesn't have a universal particle signaling the infinitive:  whether it is *à*, *de*, another preposition or no preposition at all depends on particular grammatical structure or verb, and mostly have to be remembered.

Comment: @Roger_Vadim: Thank you, that was helpful. Would à always be used after an il-y-a  structure, or would it depend on the verb?

Comment: @justerman "À" does not depend on the verb; as my answer has it, it is a part of the idiomatic turn "il y a à", which is idiomatic in the same way that "il n'y a qu'à" and "il y a de quoi" (see [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir)).